# FieldType's element attribute is null

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes, validation

I am trying to create a new entry via a form post that will come from a third party, by doing this in my plugin's service class:

```
$entry = EntryModel::populateModel(array(
    'sectionId' => 1, 
    'typeId' => 2
));

$entry->getContent()->setAttribute('reference', craft()->request->getPost('someReferenceField'));

craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

The reference field is a custom FieldType (https://github.com/fuel-digital/Craft-Unique-Text-FieldType/blob/develop/uniquetextfield/fieldtypes/UniqueTextField_UniqueTextFieldType.php) where I am validating the submitted value is unique for this EntryType (in this case an Entry rather than a User/Asset/etc).

That FieldType works fine in the control panel but I'm getting an error when submitting via my plugin as $this->element is null within the FieldType's valueExists() method.

I can get around this by creating a new EntryModel like so:

```
/**
 * Checks if another entry exists with the given value
 * 
 * @param  string $value The value to check
 * @return bool
 */
private function valueExists($value)
{
    if ( ! $this->element)
    {
        $this->element = new EntryModel();
    }

    $existing = craft()->elements->getCriteria($this->element->elementType)->first(array(
        $this->model->handle => $value
    ));

    return ($existing && $existing->id != $this->element->id);
}
```

But that means the FieldType will only work with Entry elements, and not Users, Assets etc.

As the plugin works fine in the control panel, I assume I'm missing something in my plugin service?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution by how [Entry Form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form) handles it.

Assuming you've posted fields with names such as jobData[reference]:

```
$fieldsLocation = craft()->request->getParam('fieldsLocation', 'jobData');

$this->entry->setContentFromPost($fieldsLocation);
```

The setContentFromPost() method of the EntriesController class sets the ElementType.